# Partial derivatives of $f:S\to\mathbb{R}^n$ at $a\in S$, where $S$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$. James R. Munkres "Analysis on Manifolds".

Tags: functions, partial-derivative

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> Definition. Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}^n$. We say that $f$ is of class $C^r$ on $S$ if $f$ may be extended to a function $g:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that is of class $C^r$ on an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ containing $S$.

If $g$ exists, we can define partial derivatives of $f:S\to\mathbb{R}^n$ at $a\in S$.
But the author didn't define partial derivatives of $f:S\to\mathbb{R}^n$ at $a\in S$.

I guess the partial derivative of $f:S\to\mathbb{R}^n$ at $a\in S$ with respect to an aribitrary vector $e_j$ is not useful.
So, the author didn't define it.
Am I right?

Comment: In general, there is no meaningful definition of a partial derivative in this situation. A good example to contemplate is when $S$ is a singleton. Most likely, you have in mind partial derivatives of $g$ at $a$, but these, in general, will depend on the extension $g$ and not on $f$ itself, making this a bad definition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you very much for your answer.